# simple_html_dom ignores special characters

Tags: php, url, special-characters, file-get-contents, encode

The code I am using is the one below, this works perfectly fine until I encounter url with Japanese character or any special characters. I have observed this issue and it seems that it is only returning the domain name whenever the url contains special characters such as japanese, as a result I kept getting random results which I don't intend to retrieve.

```
  include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$url_link = 'http://kissanime.com/Anime/Knights-of-Ramune-VS騎士ラムネ＆40FRESH';

$html = file_get_html($url_link);
echo $html->find('.bigChar', 0)->innertext;
```

I should be getting a result of "Knights of Ramune" since that's the element I was trying to retrieve. Instead, the $url_link was redirected to domain name which is the 'http://kissanime.com/' without 'Anime/Knights-of-Ramune-VS騎士ラムネ＆40FRESH'. And from there, it looks for the class with a value of '.bigChar' that results of giving random value.

Comment: You should echo $html to see if you are retrieving the page correctly.

Comment: It just redirects me to domain name only

Comment: Then the problem is not with simple_html_dom, but with file_get_html. I doubt URLs are allowed to contain special characters, but I don't have a reference handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Real Problem domain is, **how to retrieve the data using a URL with UTF-8 Characters**, not `simple_html_dom`.

First of all, we need to encode the characters:

```
$url_link = 'http://kissanime.com/Anime/Knights-of-Ramune-VS騎士ラムネ＆40FRESH';

$strPosLastPart  = strrpos($url_link, '/') + 1;
$lastPart        = substr($url_link, $strPosLastPart);
$encodedLastPart = rawurlencode($lastPart);
$url_link        = str_replace($lastPart, $encodedLastPart, $url_link);
```

Normaly this should work. Since i have test it, it worked not. So I am asking why this error happens, and made a Call using CURL.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Now we know, this page is written in ASP.NET. But i was asking me, why it not work. I added a User Agent, and voila:

```
$ch = curl_init($url_link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

All together (working):

```
$url_link = 'http://kissanime.com/Anime/Knights-of-Ramune-VS騎士ラムネ＆40FRESH';

//Encode Characters
$strPosLastPart  = strrpos($url_link, '/') + 1;
$lastPart        = substr($url_link, $strPosLastPart);
$encodedLastPart = rawurlencode($lastPart);
$url_link        = str_replace($lastPart, $encodedLastPart, $url_link);

//Download Data
$ch = curl_init($url_link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//Load Data into Html (untested, since i am not using this Lib)
$html = str_get_html($data);
```

Now the difference would be, to read `$data` into your `simple_html_dom.php` class, instead of `file_get_html`.

Cheers

Comment: How can I apply this using simple_html_dom.php extention?

Comment: Don't know this lib, but what about `str_get_html($data)`?